# Socket client-server connection failure using Amazon EC2 instance with Elastic IP

Tags: java, sockets, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two simple JAVA socket applications:
—One as client.
—One as server.
When I try to connect using LAN network client and server on two machines sharing one wifi everything goes fine.
I decided to upload server program to Microsoft EC2 instance and connect to it using client application on my laptop, but the connection fails even with Elastic IP associated with that instance.

What could cause a problem?

Comment: please post your code or any errors you are having.. post everything that we might need to know to help you

Answer (score 0):

You're probably experiencing a network issue.
In order to make the connection between your computer and an EC2 instance, you have to ensure:

- Your EIP(Elastic IP) is associated with your instance
- Your instance has a path to internet(default route to an IGW(Internet Gateway))
- Security groups are configured to authorize the specific port(or port range) your application is using
- Your NACLs are configured accordingly as well
- Your EC2 instance has an iptables/firewall compatible with your application needs